# How to create a Mock which has functions' special (dunder) attributes

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have some code that uses functions as parameters and I've added some logging that includes `__qualname__`, this caused my unit tests to fail since the `Mock` object I passed in raises an `AttributeError` for `__qualname__`.

```
mock_func = Mock()
```

A simple solution to this problem is to manually add the expected attribute to the mock:

```
mock_func.__qualname__ = "mock_function"
```

Or add it to the spec of the mock when I create it:

```
mock_func = Moc(["__qualname__"])
```

But these solutions are unsatisfying since I would need to change them whenever I use a different built-in attribute (e.g. `__name__`).

Is there a simple way to create a `Mock` which behaves like a function?

The closest I found was [this bug report](https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock/issues/431) that was opened on the wrong repository, and [this request](https://bugs.python.org/issue32952) which has no replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use any function as spec for the mock.

```
mock_func = Mock(spec=max)
mock_func.__qualname__
>>> <Mock name='mock.__qualname__' id='140172665218496'>
```

Comment: Good idea, however I expect this to be rather confusing for future readers of the code.

Comment: You could either put a comment or do something like `Mock(spec=lambda justforspec:0)` to make it a bit more clear, or even `def function(): pass` and use that for the spec